# Lazy Loading of Layouts

Tags: android, layout, lazy-loading

I've made a game which has lots of layouts in it, and thus takes almost 15 seconds or more to load the activity. Is there a way to load some layouts first and then load the rest of them after some time, so that the user don't have to see a black screen between activities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use **threads** for this. load some layouts outside the thread and load remaining threads in thread.
sample code for thread.

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //write your code here...
        }
    }, delay_time);
```

Comment: I used your code to call the layout creation methods inside the run() method, it does what I wanted, but slowed down my app, including some ANR dialogs which were not there before. Is there any explanation for the same??

Comment: create layout ids outside the run method but set their visibility as VISIBLE in run method

Answer (score 1):

If it possible get rid off how many layouts you can. If you want to display activity without delay you can try to hardcoding some layouts and add them in different thread with delay.

Comment: Will I be able to access the layouts in the main thread then? I guess the UIs can be accessed in the thread which has created them.

Comment: I think yes, I've got right now AsyncTask with adding new views and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well, lazy initialization generally can be archived like this

```
private View v;
...
v.getSomethingUsefullFromView();    

public int getSomethingUsefullFromView () {
if(v == null)
    v = new View()
    jadajada

return somevalue;
}
```

The trick here is to have that `if(v == null) v = new View()` snippet

That way you will only initialize the View v when you actually need to.

Comment: Normally you'd also have an initFoobarView() which you will refer to in every get method, but that depends entirely on how much work you need to do, to initialize.

Answer (score 0):

Another nice way to load layouts lazily is to use `ViewStub` entries in your layout as described here https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/loading-ondemand

Basically you define a `ViewStub` entry in your layout referring to another layout file where you put the contents that you want to load. Those contents aren't loaded until you set the visibility of your stub to `VISIBLE`. After that the stub itself disappears and you can work with your loaded subview/layout.